# Do any PEPs specify whether new code should be Python 2 compatible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Making the following code Python 2-compatible is as simple as removing the return at the end of the function definition (`-> None`).

```
import csv
fieldnames = ['this', 'is', 'unimportant', 'spam', 'eggs']
def create_log_file(fname) -> None:
    """ If log file exists, does nothing, else creates log file

    Arguments:
        fname {str} -- The name of the log file
    """
    try:
        f = open(fname, "r")
        f.close()
    except IOError:
        with open(fname, "w") as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
```

Is it preferable to make it backwards-compatible, or should we be more explicit where possible since Python 3 allows us to (in which case I can also remove the `IOError or` part)?

**Or is "Python 2 compatibility" vs. "Explicit is better than implicit" just a matter of personal preference?**

Comment: It's not preferrable to sacrifice features only for Python 2 compatibility, since Python 2 is deprecated already.

Comment: Python 2 support ended on 2020-01-01. It’s up to you whether or not you support Python 2, but there are no PEPs that tell you to support it.

Comment: Python 2 has reached end of life. Do you really want to write code for Python 2? And look at bigger projects like Django. The current version already dropped support for Python <= 3.5.

Comment: As an aside, the except line should be `except (IOError, FileNotFoundError)`. `IOError or FileNotFoundError` would evaluate to `IOError`.

Comment: @Alasdair it seemed to compile fine. Anyway, updated the question to account for that, thanks

Comment: Your way runs without error, but it doesn’t do what you expect it to. Try out `IOError or FileNotFoundError` in the Python shell. It returns `IOError`. The same thing happens when you use `or` in the `Except` line, so the code is equivalent to `except IOError`.

Comment: Interesting. Since [Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError.filename2), `IOError` is now an alias for `OSError`, so it catches `FileNotFoundError` as well. So that line can just be reduced to `except IOError`, which will handle both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to make it Python 2 compatible? Python 3 was released over a decade ago, and Python 2 has officially reached it's end of life, and is no longer officially supported by the CPython developers, and [many major python projects](https://python3statement.org/) have dropped support for Python 2.

Comment: A valid reason to make something Python 2 compatible would be "my employer still uses a mix of Python 2 and 3". Other than that, you should just use Python 3.

Comment: Python 2's officially reached its end of life, but the rest of the file has always been backwards compatible and run via a cron script. I can update every function in the files and should be able to update the calling scripts too. Given that all of the functions I wrote were written in such a way as to support both, it seems a shame to drop Python 2 support simply to increase readability. Cheers